# resque scheduler not enqueue jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, resque-scheduler

Schedules exist to be executed at certain times as defined in the schedule, but the tasks are not executed.

There is an option in the schedule to manually start that specific scheduled task and that will execute and perform the tasks. This shows that the task can be performed, it is just not starting automatically.

Comment: @R.Barzell I tried to restart scheduler and workers but no success. Check job class code if there is any error. Also check logs but there is nothing written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues here:

1. There are some resque and resque scheduler processes are running from old release path (Capistrano create folder for each release and do symlink the “current” to latest release path). This leads to incorrect jobs picking for some schedules
2. The current upstart script for resque scheduler doesn’t include dynamic schedules, so the dynamic schedules don’t be picked.